# What is wrong with my dynamically allocated file line reader

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic, malloc, realloc

Constraints I have on my function is that it reads from a stream, file or standard input, and that it reads up to a newline and finished when EOF is detected.

```
char* getLine(FILE* stream)
{
    int capacity = LINE_MAX;
    char* buffer = malloc(capacity);
    int len = 0;
    char ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if (ch == EOF)
            return NULL;
        if (len >= capacity) {
            capacity *= 2;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, len * sizeof(char));
        }
        buffer[len++] = ch;
    }
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return buffer;
}
```

I cannot expect to have a specific length for my input. My main problem is, when using this in main;

```
int main()
{
    FILE* stream = stdin; // stdin now
    while (true) {
        char cmd[COMMAND_MAX];
        char* arg;
        char* rest;
        char* line;

        printf("command $: ");
        line = getLine(stream);

        if (line == NULL) {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        arg = malloc(REMAINING_MAX * sizeof(char));
        rest = malloc(REMAINING_MAX * sizeof(char));
        int arguments = sscanf(line, "%s %s %[^\n]s", cmd, arg, rest);
        free(arg);
        printf("\n");
        printf("%s, %s, %s", cmd, arg, rest);
        free(rest);
        free(line);
        return 0;
}
```

When I hit enter, on the actual program, I would receive duplicated input, almost as if it hasn't entered in the data. It just is stuck in memory. If I had done this with a scanf, it works perfectly but the issue is I cannot dynamically allocate memory for it as I found out earlier.

Comment: There are a lot of problems. BTW, Is this the actual code? Since there is an `return` sentence in while-loop, it seems that `getline` will  be called only once, unlike your explanation.

Comment: What do you mean, duplicated input?

Comment: `free(arg);   .... printf("%s, %s, %s", cmd, arg, rest);` --> is a problem as code attempts to use `arg`, a free'd pointer.

Comment: Review this code `while ((ch = fgetc(stream)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if (ch == EOF)
            return NULL;`  How would `ch == EOF` become true?

Comment: Don't ignore your compiler warnings. `fgetc` returns an `int`. You are assigning it to a char. *On success, the character read is returned (promoted to an int value).
The return type is int to accommodate for the special value EOF, which indicates failure:*